# batch file to run jar file with parameters

Tags: java, batch-file, jar

How can I run a batch file and pass parameters to jar file?

this doesn't work

**mybat.bat**

```
java -jar log_parser.jar %1 %2 %3 %4
```

running bat file

```
C:\>log_parser.bat -file=C:\\trace_small.log -str=Storing
```

java sees only `-file`

Comment: Its sounds like you are doing something wrong.  If you tell us what you means by "doesn't work" perhaps we can give you a more specific answer.

Comment: java sees only part of the arguments

Comment: Did you try putting quotes around the whole first argument, like "-file=C:\\trace_small.log"? If so, does it behave any differently?

Comment: @normalocity, yes, in this case it works! But it's a not nice way to resolve the problem :)

Comment: @Peter Lawrey, it sees: -file

Comment: Double quotes changes the behaviour of the shell. If this makes a difference, there is nothing the application can do about it.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I just tried with a small java program that only dumps the arguments to the screen:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    for(String s : args)
    {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

and the following batch file :

```
java -jar test.jar %1 %2 %3 %4
```

and I ended up with the following result

```
-file
C:\\trace_small.log
-str
Storing
```

For the same command line as you... the equal sign '=' desapeared.
Now if you trun the batch file to this :

```
java -jar test.jar %*
```

you will get yet another result (which might be what you expected - not clear)

```
-file=C:\\trace_small.log
-str=Storing
```

The advantage on this %* syntax, is that it is more extensible by accepting any number of arguments.

Hope this helps, but I recommend you to have a look at your code to and add some debug statement to understand where you are "lossing" some part of the input.

Answer (score 0):

1)
You could try to use

> "-Dfile=C:\trace_small.log
>   -Dstr=Storing"

The variables would be set as Java System Property, but not as Parameters into a main-method.

2)
Try to put the arguments without '='

> log_parser.bat -file
>   C:\trace_small.log -str Storing

Answer (score 0):

In my case I use the following bat-file:

```
@echo off
PATH_TO_JRE\bin\java.exe -jar -Denable=true your_file.jar
```

At this particular case then in java code I can get the param "enable" like this:

```
Boolean.getBoolean("enable")
```

Answer (score 0):

For Example Opening Street Map Editor in Windows 10 x64

```
> cd "C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_161\bin\"

> javaw.exe -Xmx2048m -jar "C:\Program Files (x86)\JOSM\josm-tested.jar"
```

Comment: OP wants to run batch file with parameters, not run the jar directly.